# NGINX reverse proxy and swagger-ui.html

Tags: nginx, swagger, reverse-proxy

I have been trying to get swagger to work behind a NGINX reverse proxy, but I just cannot get it right. My services are running in docker containers and I would like to access them with these sample urls:

My service:

```
http://service-host.example.com/my-service1
```

Swagger:

```
http://service-host.example.com/my-service1/api
```

My nested location blocks look like this:

```
location /my-service1 {
  resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
  set $upstream my-host.example.com;
  proxy_pass http://$upstream/home;

      location ~ /api {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
            set $upstream my-host.example.com;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream/swagger-ui.html;
      }
      location ~ /webjars {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
            set $upstream my-host.example.com;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
      }
      location ~ /v2 {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
            set $upstream my-host.example.com;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
      }
      location ~ /swagger-resources {
            resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
            set $upstream my-host.example.com;
            proxy_pass http://$upstream/;
      }
}
```

My NGINX log looks something like this:

```
GET /my-service1/api/ HTTP/2.0" 200
GET /my-service1/api/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.css?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200
GET /my-service1/api/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200
GET /my-service1/api/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200
GET /my-service1/api/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200
GET /my-service1/api/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200
```

Testing this directly, without going via NGINX, the process proceeds further, with GETs to /v2/api and /swagger-resources. Using the reverse proxy gets stuck just before that.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

EDIT: Here is a NGINX log when not trying to reverse proxy, but going directly to http://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html where it works perfectly!

```
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:44 +0000] "GET /swagger-ui.html HTTP/2.0" 200 3318 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:44 +0000] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.css?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200 2894 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:44 +0000] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui.css?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200 154488 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:45 +0000] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-bundle.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200 1448844 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:45 +0000] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/springfox.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200 96207 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:45 +0000] "GET /webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js?v=2.9.2 HTTP/2.0" 200 440850 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:46 +0000] "GET /swagger-resources/configuration/ui HTTP/2.0" 200 450 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:46 +0000] "GET /swagger-resources/configuration/security HTTP/2.0" 200 2 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:46 +0000] "GET /swagger-resources HTTP/2.0" 200 90 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
myservice.example.com 192.168.1.30 - - [12/Feb/2019:09:59:46 +0000] "GET /v2/api-docs HTTP/2.0" 200 8387 "https://myservice.example.com/swagger-ui.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
```

Comment: did you check in your browser the content of the requests that you are making? My assumption would be that while the url is being resolved, nginx is not returning the file that swagger needs to initialize the UI.

Answer (score 0):

swagger working in my server (NET CORE) with this conf

```
    location / {
        #root   /srv/ftp;
        #index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```